# Conda ImportError: No yaml library available

Tags: linux-mint, anaconda, conda

Linux Mint 18. Может это произошло после обновления Anaconda navigator. Теперь в терминале среда не видит никакие программы  (такие как jupyter-notebook, Spyder. [На Windows 10 такое тоже произошло, но мне казалось из-за того, что из-за плохой совместимости xtensor и conda.{тогда я тоже обновлял пакеты и заголовки.}]). При почти всех команда conda, и при открытии нового терминала, тот выводит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 19, in get_yaml
    import ruamel_yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 22, in get_yaml
    import ruamel.yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1062, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 74, in _main
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, ConfigurationLoadError, MapParameter,
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .serialize import yaml_load
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 30, in <module>
    yaml = get_yaml()
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 59, in _memoized_func
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 24, in get_yaml
    raise ImportError("No yaml library available.\n"
ImportError: No yaml library available.
To proceed, conda install ruamel_yaml

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 19, in get_yaml
    import ruamel_yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 22, in get_yaml
    import ruamel.yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1354, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1065, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1109, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1120, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1175, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .base.context import context
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, ConfigurationLoadError, MapParameter,
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .serialize import yaml_load
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 30, in <module>
    yaml = get_yaml()
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 59, in _memoized_func
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/timur/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 24, in get_yaml
    raise ImportError("No yaml library available.\n"
ImportError: No yaml library available.
To proceed, conda install ruamel_yaml
```

Как я могу починить это?

Comment: На ru.stackoverflow.com вопросы нужно задавать на русском

Comment: хмм, не заметил, что на ру зашёл